# Solving a PermGen issue on redeploy with Jetty 7

Tags: java, maven, jetty, el, permgen

After a couple of days of debugging I have managed to have a medium-to-large web application redeploy successfully on Tomcat 6.0.32 without any `PermGen` leaks. I saw the `PermGen` drop after it filled, and the classloaders were garbage collected.

After much rejoicing I tried to make the application redeploy without leaks on our development environment, which is composed of Maven and the Jetty plugin.

Unfortunately I seem to have hit a server limitation, as illustrated by the below screenshot

[Yourkit snapshot http://img811.imageshack.us/img811/7320/jettyclassloaderbeanelr.png](http://img811.imageshack.us/img811/7320/jettyclassloaderbeanelr.png)

Jetty request threads have a strong reference to a `BeanElResolver` which in turns has a strong reference to multiple classes from my webapp.

I have found no reference on how to flush this information.

How can I remove this final `PermGen` leak from my application?

---

Update:

I've done the following to fix the problem, with no luck:

- updated to the Latest version of the Jetty Plugin ( both 7.4.5 and 8.0.0.M3 )
- used the CMS collector : `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled`

---

Update 2:

- I've reported this as a bug on the Jetty issue tracker: [maven-jetty-plugin: PermGen leak due to javax.el.BeanELResolver](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=353095)

Comment: I don't understand your wording. What do you mean with PermGen-Leak? Did you try to give soem GC related flags to the VM like: -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled ?

Do you expect a running web app to be completely collected when no connection/session is up?

Comment: Angel: by default, your servlet container leaks classloaders on each redeploy. Class definitions are allocated out of the permanent generation, so you will get a PermGen leak. I'm impressed the OP managed to circumvent this problem with Tomcat 6 and no flags.

Comment: Robert: please consider telling us more about what you did to fix the leak in Tomcat 6! I'd love to know what you did. Wiki, perhaps?

Comment: @Angel: I don't use the CMS garbage collector, so I don't need to specify those flags. And with PermGen leak I mean that on undeploy the old classloader instance remains pinned in memory, not allowing the classes to be garbage collected.

Comment: That is why I suggested to use the other GC, the standard GC does not collect permgen at all, IIRC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a actual bug in the EL implementation which is worked around in the latest Jetty versions.

Version 7.5.0, once released, will contain the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, but you might consider using [JRebel](http://www.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/) in dev. With JRebel, you mostly don't *have* to redeploy, thus avoiding both the permgen leaks and the wasted time of a redeploy. It's been working extremely well for me.

Comment: I already use JRebel, but a) I sometimes have to restart, b) not everyone in my team does so I need to find a better solution for them as well.